# iPhone - Objective C - Nimbus compiling errors when adding NIAttributedLabel module

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nimbus

I'm switching to Nimbus in order to replace Three20 in my project.
When I added AttributedLabel module to the project, I see 24 compile errors.
This is one of them:
Do you know how to fix it?
**(When I remove AttributedLabel from my project, I can compile the project.)**

```
Ld /Users/return/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bmmfgcavsjqopdfantffsvnydpqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal i386
    cd /Users/return/Projects/Experiments/MyApp
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Xcode4.3.2/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Xcode4.3.2/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Xcode4.3.2/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Xcode4.3.2/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/return/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bmmfgcavsjqopdfantffsvnydpqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/return/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bmmfgcavsjqopdfantffsvnydpqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/return/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bmmfgcavsjqopdfantffsvnydpqj/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -o /Users/return/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bmmfgcavsjqopdfantffsvnydpqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel sizeThatFits:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
      -[NIAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel sizeThatFits:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTLineGetTypographicBounds", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel getLineBounds:point:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFrameGetLines", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel linkAtPoint:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
      -[NIAttributedLabel isPoint:nearLink:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
      -[NIAttributedLabel _rectsForLink:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
      -[NIAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFrameGetLineOrigins", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel linkAtPoint:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
      -[NIAttributedLabel isPoint:nearLink:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
      -[NIAttributedLabel _rectsForLink:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
      -[NIAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel linkAtPoint:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTLineGetGlyphRuns", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel _rectForRange:inLine:lineOrigin:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTRunGetStringRange", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel _rectForRange:inLine:lineOrigin:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTRunGetTypographicBounds", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel _rectForRange:inLine:lineOrigin:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel _rectForRange:inLine:lineOrigin:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFramesetterCreateFrame", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTLineGetStringRange", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFrameDraw", referenced from:
      -[NIAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in NIAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTParagraphStyleCreate", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setTextAlignment:lineBreakMode:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFontCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setFont:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
  "_kCTFontAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setFont:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
  "_kCTForegroundColorAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setTextColor:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
  "_kCTKernAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setKern:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
  "_kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setTextAlignment:lineBreakMode:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
  "_kCTStrokeColorAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setStrokeColor:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
  "_kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setStrokeWidth:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
  "_kCTUnderlineColorAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setUnderlineStyle:modifier:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
  "_kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[NSMutableAttributedString(NimbusAttributedLabel) setUnderlineStyle:modifier:range:] in NSMutableAttributedString+NimbusAttributedLabel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the demo "CustomTextAttributedLabelViewController.m":

```
// This controller requires the following frameworks:
//
// Foundation.framework
// UIKit.framework
**// CoreText.framework**
// QuartzCore.framework
```